# selecting any one of the unanswered multiple-choice questions in MariaDB/MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/65127) (The fiddle isn't really working to me)

I'd like to fetch any one of the multiple-choice questions that haven't been answered by a user whose id is `99`. He has only answered one question - `A question` so far as seen in `user_answer` table which stores the `choice id` instead of the question_id.

My expected result should be like this:

```
Question    Question_id Choice_id  Choice
B question       2        3        B choice 1
B question       2        4        B choice 2
```

Or

```
C question       3        5        C choice 1
C question       3        6        C choice 2
C question       3        7        C choice 3
```

With the following Sql, I'm having trouble fetching just either B or C question with its choices

```
SELECT q.question_id,q.question,qc.choice,qc.choice_id         
FROM question_choice qc
INNER JOIN question q ON q.question_id = qc.question_id
WHERE qc.question_id NOT IN 
(SELECT question_id 
   FROM user_answer ua
   INNER JOIN question_choice qc ON qc.choice_id = ua.choice_id
   WHERE ua.user_id = 99)
GROUP BY qc.choice_id
ORDER BY q.question_id;
```

I'm not sure what to put in the `limit clause` to fetch just one unanswered question with the variable number of choices.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE question 
(question_id INT, question VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE question_choice
(question_id INT, choice_id INT,choice VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE user_answer
(user_id INT,choice_id INT);

INSERT INTO question (question_id,question) 
VALUES
(1,"A question"),
(2,"B question"),
(3,"C question");

INSERT INTO question_choice (choice_id,choice,question_id)
VALUES
(1,"A choice 1",1),
(2,"A choice 2",1),
(3,"B choice 1",2),
(4,"B choice 2",2),
(5,"C choice 1",3),
(6,"C choice 2",3),
(7,"C choice 3",3);

INSERT INTO user_answer(user_id,choice_id)
VALUES
(99,2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  But this might help you think about arriving at the solution.

First, you can get the list of *questions* that are not answered by using a query such as this:

```
SELECT q.*  
FROM question q
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT question_id 
                  FROM user_answer ua INNER JOIN
                       question_choice qc
                       ON qc.choice_id = ua.choice_id
                  WHERE ua.user_id = 99 AND qc.question_id = q.question_id
                 );
```

Note that I replaced `NOT IN` with `NOT EXISTS`.  Because they treat `NULL` values differently, I strongly suggest using `NOT EXISTS` -- the treatment of `NULL` values is more intuitive.

You can then use this in a query to get the rest of the information about the unanswered questions:

```
SELECT q.question_id, q.question, qc.choice, qc.choice_id 
FROM (SELECT q.*  
      FROM question q
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT question_id 
                        FROM user_answer ua INNER JOIN
                             question_choice qc
                             ON qc.choice_id = ua.choice_id
                        WHERE ua.user_id = 99 AND qc.question_id = q.question_id
                       )
     ) q JOIN
     question_choice qc
     ON qc.question_id = q.question_id;
```

If you like, you can work on how to "simplify" this query by removing the subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      q.question_id
      ,q.question
    FROM
      question_choice qc
      INNER JOIN question q
      ON q.question_id = qc.question_id
      LEFT JOIN user_answer ua
      ON qc.choice_id = ua.choice_id
      AND ua.user_id = 99
    WHERE
       ua.user_id IS NULL
    LIMIT 1
   ) nq
   INNER JOIN question_choice nqc
   ON nq.question_id = nqc.question_id
```

I like the `LEFT JOIN` model but the `NOT EXISTS()` structure works too.

Comment: Matt, thanks. I need any one of the unanswered questions only, but your sql is fetching all of the unanswered questions.

Comment: No problem Just add LIMIT 1 and order by how you want the question to be chosen.  Do you always want it to be the first unique id unanswered, random?  Question only or the choices as well?

Comment: Sorry I answered my own question do the LIMIT1 and then just join that back to the question_choice table and grab the choices.  Answer is updated.